# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java program to check if double is negative

Tags: java, arrays, double, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to write a simple program (using the type double) that checks if the number is negative or not.

I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>   at NegativeZahl.main(NegativeZahl.java:7)

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class NegativeZahl {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
     String eingabe;
     double zahl = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
     eingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Geben Sie eine Zahl ein!");
     if ( zahl >= 1) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,zahl + "Die Zahl ist    positiv" );
     } else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, zahl + "Die Zahl ist negativ");
     }

    }

   }
```

Comment: You should check `args.length`

Comment: How are you running it? Did you pass at least one argument to to your program?

Comment: `zahl >=1` means `zahl` is positive, otherwise `zahl` is negative?  By that logic, both -1/2 and   1/2 are negative!  Maybe you meant `zahl >= 0`, which is closer to the truth...

Answer (score 1):

Your program mixes up two ways to get the number:

You fill the value `zahl` from the command line `args[0]`, meaning you have to run your program with something like `java NegativeZahl 123.4` with 123.4 being the number you want to test.

But you also open a dialog to ask the user for entering a number, but then do nothing with his input `eingabe`.

The error looks like you didn't provide the number on the command line.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that you haven't run this program with argument like java program_name